# Scala on Intellij

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, intellij-idea, azure-blob-storage

When I set up a scala project on intellij I compile and run it locally.
I have a line in it as follows

```
println("Test")
```

In the output "Test" appears. I believe this is the job's Java System.out. Correct me if i'm wrong.
When I run the same scala project (jar) file from intellij, I submit it through intellij  (Azure toolkit for intellij) to a spark cluster I have spun up on azure. I do not see the outputs.
I do not see "Test" in the window at the bottom.

1. where can i see the outputs?
2. if i can't see the outputs, can i write them to a text file somewhere on blob storage? If so, how?

Comment: basically what u want to know is to see output on the console right ? u can use println() in scala right ? also if u want to see any data being calculated u can place debug point in ur code and stop at the debug place.

Comment: Yeah, I can see println when I run the scala code locally. But not on azure. How is the developer meant to get feedback when submitting jobs on spark on azure? (Obviously println("test") is a very simple example. In reality, I want to load large datasets up and do things like aggregate data and get averages etc and println those, so I can see what I'm working with)

Comment: You can use println() to seed the output on console, You can also use some notebooks like zeppelin or jupyter to see output or write to any filesystems to see the output. I am also usig the Azure clusters and blob storage.

Comment: I was originally using zeppelin, but got frustrated with it. I have classes in .scala files I was looking to reference them in the zeppelin notebook, but didn't know how to do it. So I went down the "intellij, submit jobs route"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend checking the following [documentation](https://github.com/nickfloyd/azure-content/blob/master/articles/hdinsight/hdinsight-apache-spark-intellij-tool-plugin-debug-jobs-remotely.md) , although it specifically mentions remote debugging, there is a section in the screenshots highlighting the console.
You could also check the following documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-intellij-tool-debug-remotely-through-ssh

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Will do. Thanks Adam Smith. Any relation?

Comment: yes :) there are options for debugging which will show the output when using println() through the console.